# how to show messagebox when wpf app closing?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, messagebox

I have a WPF app with MVVM pattern and it contains following 2 views:

1:`MainWindow.xaml` (it's a window)
below is main portion of `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:XliffListViewModel}">
        <vw:XliffListView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Margin="4">
    <Border Background="GhostWhite" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" >
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}" Margin="4" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

2:`XliffListView.xaml` (it's a user control)
 XliffListView contain a datagrid and a button for save all changes that happens

I want to show messagebox when user closing app if changes not saved

Answer (score 0):

You can write and `Attached behavior` that handles `Window.Closing()` event of the Window and executes the `ClosingCommand` from `ViewModel` and returns true or false as parameter so that one can cancel (`e.Cancel`) closing event if the VM wants to stop th window from closing.

The code below is just for concept and is not complete

**XAML**

```
  <Window x:Class="..."
          ...
          myBheaviors:WindowBehaviors.ClosingCommand="{Binding MyClosingCommand}">
      ...
  </Window>
```

**ViewModel**

```
  public class MyWindowViewModel 
  {
      public ICommand MyClosingCommand
      {
          get
             { 
                 if (_myClosingCommand == null)
                    _myClosingCommand 
                       = new DelegateCommand<CancelEventArgs>(OnClosing);
                 return _myClosingCommand;
             }
      }

      private void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
      {
          if (this.Dirty) //Some function that decides if the VM has pending changes.
              e.Cancel = true;
      }
  }
```

**Attached Behavior**

```
  public static class WindowBehaviors
  {
      public static readonly DependencyProperty ClosingCommandProperty
         = DependencyProperty.RegistsrrAttached(
                "ClosingCommand", 
                ..., 
                new PropertyMetataData(OnClosingCommandChanged);

      public static ICommand GetClosingCommand(...) { .. };

      public static void SetClosingCommand(...) { .. };

      private static void OnClosingCommandChanged(sender, e)
      {
           var window = sender as Window;
           var command = e.NewValue as ICommand;
           if (window != null && command != null)
           {
               window.Closing 
                  += (o, args) => 
                     { 
                         command.Execute(args);
                         if (args.Cancel)
                         {
                             MessageBox.Show(
                                "Window has pending changes. Cannot close");

                             // Now window will be stopped from closing.
                         }
                     };     
           } 
      }
  }
```

**EDIT:**

For user controls, instead of `Closing` use `Unloaded` event.

Also try to establish a hierarchy between `ViewModel`s i.e.e Window's ViewModel should contain UserControl's ViewModel. So that `Closing` event's IsDirty() call can scrutinize the UserControls' ViewModel also.

Comment: MainWindowViewModel and XliffListViewModel and i want to check changes in XliffListViewModel that it join to XliffListView.xaml that it's a usercontrol not a window!